# tcplistener/tcpclient await is stopping code after from running

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

This code outputs "8096" 13 times as expected (ceil(100,000/8096) = 13)

But then after the while loops in both functions nothing else runs but program finishes, the 2 console.writlelines after them don't get run (does work printing before, just not after the while loop)

Here is my code:

Tcpclient function:

```
public static async void Main()
{       
    using TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost",50000);
    using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] data = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(100000);
    await stream.WriteAsync(data,0,data.Length);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8096];
    int i;
    while((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))>0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("this doesnt get printed");
    client.Close();
    return;
}
```

tcplistener function:

```
public static async void Main()
{               
    try
    {   
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,50000);
        server.Start();
        using TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8096];
        byte[] return_bytes = new byte[8096];
        int i;
        while((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))>0)
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(return_bytes,0,return_bytes.Length);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("this doesn't get printed");
        client.Close();
        server.Stop();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("port already in use");
    }
}
```

Tried making it synchronous and putting them in threads but that didn't work

Comment: Well why are you swallowing exceptions? Looks like at some point you are going to send so much data, that you fill the buffer of the listener machine. It in turn cannot empty it, because it's trying to echo it back to the client, which isn't receiving because it's busy sending. You need to move sending and receiving into different tasks using `Task.Run`. See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html#reading Furthermore you seem to be makng a common mistake: a send from the client is not necessarily a single packet down the wire, which is not ...

Comment: ... necessarily a single receive result on the listener socket. TCP is an unending stream of bytes which may be split or joined as seen fit. See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: @Charlieface that was a quick fix for testing to get around the error kept saying socket was already in use as the server.close() is not getting closed after the while loop on tcplistener class

Comment: Well how is that possible if the application has already ended, at which point the socket gets closed? Is this really a `Main()` function of a console app or not? Are you getting any other exceptions? And why `async void` and not `async Task`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hand off the reading to another task or thread, as otherwise the client is blocked waiting for the listener, which in turn is blocked waiting to echo to the client, which is still blocked trying to send.

```cs
public static async Task Main()
{       
    byte[] data = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(100000);
    using TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync("localhost", 50000);  // connect asynchronously
    using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();   // needs using
    var task = Task.Run(async () => {      // hand off reads
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8096];
        int i;
        while((i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    });
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    await task;  // wait for reads to finish
    Console.WriteLine("this doesnt get printed");
}
```

See also [@StephenCleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html#reading) for more.

Comment: I tried running this as the client code but it returned same result

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly.  You send 100000 bytes and receive 100000 bytes echo'd back to you.

You then sit waiting for the server to send more data, but the server will only send more data if it receives data.

So the client will await forever waiting for the server to send it some data.  The server will await for ever waiting for the client to send it some data.

If you want the program to continue or exit, then you need to either send more data or exit the loop after you have processed the 100000 bytes.